# Django transaction test case raises IntegrityError with data migration on sqlite

Tags: python, django, sqlite, data-migration

I'm trying to port an existing django 1.6 project with tests using LiveServerTestCase to django 1.7. I've converted the initial_data fixtures to data migrations. When I did that all my live server tests failed because the data was being flushed. I then stumbled upon the serialized_rollback option for TransactionTestCase and added that to my test classes. However now I'm getting the following error when I run my tests:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_content_type.app_label, django_content_type.model
```

I've replicated the problem in a sample app here: https://github.com/tctimmeh/djangomigrate

The model:

```
class SomeData(Model):
    value = IntegerField()
```

The data migration:

```
def createData(apps, schema_editor):
    SomeData = apps.get_model('mtestapp', 'SomeData')
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    SomeData.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        SomeData(value = 1),
    ])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('mtestapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]
    operations = [
        RunPython(createData)
    ]
```

And the tests:

```
class TestIt(TransactionTestCase):
    serialized_rollback = True
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, SomeData.objects.all().count())
    def test_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, SomeData.objects.all().count())
```

One of those tests pass. The other raises the above-mentioned IntegrityError. Any idea why this might be?

**Edit**: I dug into it a bit more and it looks like the django.contrib.contenttypes app has a post_migrate management command that runs after the test database is flushed. Is there a way to prevent that command from running maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Django 1.9: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23727

For earlier versions I worked around this problem by re-creating my static data as a setup step for every test.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with same problem at different circumstances. 
I removed `serialized_rollback = True` and added test data manually in the setUp() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add your application to available_apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.available_apps) so that Django behave as if only the models from this application are available. In your test case, you then have:

```
class TestIt(TransactionTestCase):
  serialized_rollback = True
  available_apps = ['mtestapp']

  def test_one(self):
    self.assertTrue(True)

  def test_two(self):
    self.assertTrue(True)
```